# ExifTool does not extract corrupted EXIF metadata from jpeg file. How to repair it?

Tags: metadata, jpeg, exiftool, data-corruption

The image viewer [nomacs](https://nomacs.org/) offers a quick way to [add image notes](https://nomacs.org/image-notes) via `Exif.Image.ImageDescription` metadata.

After having edited the form for `my-image.jpg`, I can see  this property in nomacs and Thunar (Linux Xfce file explorer).

But exiftool will *not* show it:

```
exiftool my-image.jpg
```

The following has also been tried after having read [this post](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=4120.0):

```
exiftool -EXIF:ImageDescription my-image.jpg
exiftool -Exif:ImageDescription my-image.jpg
```

I need a way to process the image notes via CLI and would like to use exiftool for this purpose. Hence: what have I missed?

Comment: Have you try `exiftool -a my-image.jpg` and the filter the output?

Comment: @RomeoNinov just tried the `-a` switch, unfortunately no additional effect (same with `-e`, `-ee`, `-u`).

Comment: This mean for me the software do not store the note in to the image, maybe its a bug.

Comment: Hm, this is strange. Thunar file explorer is completely independent from nomacs and also shows me for `my-image.jpg` -> Properties -> Image -> Description -> `test123`, where `test123` has been my given note text.

Comment: Have you tried the command in [exiftool FAQ #3](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q3) and search through all the data in the file to see the actual location of your data?

Comment: I just installed nomacs and tested the Panels->Image Notes feature as per your link and it correctly wrote to `EXIF:ImageDescription`.

Comment: Thank you very much for testing that out. Let me try that on a different machine to rule uncertainities out

Comment: @StarGeek ah I see - my issue rather seems to be related to the network file system/path/permissions and neither nomacs nor exiftool. If I repeat the same sequence with an image file, that is stored somewhere on the *local* disk path, metadata gets correctly written. Anyway, thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction!  I guess, I need to investigate a bit further, why that happens for network files.

Comment: Update: Nope, network hasn't been the problem neither. It seems, some image files are sufficiently corrupted, so that exiftool cannot/refuses to read metadata anymore. Some images on my network storage can be changed, others not.

Comment: Are they all jpgs or is there some other format.  For example, BMP files can't hold any metadata.

Comment: Yes, they all are .jpg. Unfortunately I cannot share them here, as company files. I see, if this can be reproduced with public files.

Comment: I did notice that nomacs doesn't actually save the data in the file *until* you close the program.  So even though I hit the save icon a bunch of times, nothing will show up in exiftool until I exit the program.

Comment: @StarGeek good hint, can confirm latency issues. But the specific .jpg file at hand *actually* seems to have corrupt meta data, I cannot write the `ImageDescription`. Is there a way (preferrably by exiftool) to clean/sanitize the image metadata storage area to give it a fresh try?

Comment: @ramo, to cleanup you can use command `exiftool -all= path_to_file`

Comment: @RomeoNinov works, thanks! Of course, this deletes all other metadata, but fine regarding image metadata apparently being buggy as a whole. You can post that as answer, if you want and I will happily accept it.

Comment: I would suggest [exiftool FAQ #20](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q20), which will rewrite the metadata and save as much as possible.  Additional note, ***NEVER*** use `-all=` or FAQ 20 on a RAW image (NEF, ARW, CR2, etc), as it can be permanently corrupted by such images.  ETA: ah, I see @ramo beat me to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the discussion in comments seems like metadata of this image file is corrupted. What you can do is to cleanup the metadata and try again:

```
exiftool -all= path_to_file
```

Be aware this will remove all the metadata from the file. If you want to remove only particular metadata you can use command like:

```
exiftool -EXIF:ImageDescription= path_to_file
```

To get the exact name you can use command:

```
exiftool -a path_to_file
```

Comment: This is great. When I have more rep, I will upvote your answer as well

Comment: Btw: I also have found a method, that tries to preserve existing tags and post this as alternative answer

Comment: @ramo updoot to ya. =)

Answer (score 3):

(In addition to [Romeo Ninov's great answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/125211/99611))

There is an [Exiftool FAQ](https://exiftool.org/faq.html#Q20) alternative, that tries to repair JPEG file-metadata *and* preserve existing tags:

```
exiftool -all= -tagsfromfile @ -all:all -unsafe -icc_profile my-image.jpg
```

> ExifTool may be used to fix metadata problems in JPEG images by deleting all metadata and rebuilding it from scratch. [...]

> This command deletes all metadata then copies all writable tags that can be extracted from the original image to the same locations in the updated image. The `"Unsafe"` tag is a [shortcut](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/Shortcuts.html) for unsafe EXIF tags in JPEG images which are not normally copied. JPEG images may also contain an ICC color profile which should be preserved. The `"ICC_Profile"` tag is also marked as unsafe, but is not part of the EXIF so it isn't covered by the `"Unsafe"` shortcut and must be specified separately.

> After repairing an image like this you should be able to write to it without errors, but note that **some metadata from the original image may have been lost in the process**.

> Note: ExifTool will not modify the JPEG image data, so if the image itself is corrupted (eg. if you get a message saying "Not a valid JPEG"), then ExifTool can not be used to repair the image. Also, ExifTool may not be used like this to repair TIFF-based files or RAW files -- the risk of image corruption is too great because the image is stored in the same IFD as the metadata in these files.